# Indicates who the user shares the Facebook's posts with - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook

I have a post to Facebook functionality in my app[image]. 
Upon success I want to check who the player shared the post with.
My intention is to avoid the success progress in case he chose the "Only me" option.

Is it possible? any ideas?

Comment: success is that the user hasn't canceled the pop up .
i.e: FBWebDialogResult = FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted.
I need it for analysing.

Comment: You don’t get that information back directly. If you get a post id back, then you can look up the post via API afterwards, and check its privacy setting.

Comment: Do you have some sample code for it by any chance?

Comment: If you want to cancel the dialog mid share, this is not possible. You can't control who this person decides to post with, although as @CBroe mentions, AFTER the person has posted you can check who he posted this with.

Comment: How do I check who he shared his with?

Are you referring to post with as tagged friends or the content's share preferences? Just want to see that we are on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer for that if it interests someone:

```
NS_ENUM
Passed to open to indicate which default audience to use for sessions that post data to Facebook.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSDKDefaultAudience) {
FBSDKDefaultAudienceFriends = 0,
FBSDKDefaultAudienceOnlyMe,
FBSDKDefaultAudienceEveryone,
};
Constant    Description
FBSDKDefaultAudienceFriends 
Indicates that the user's friends are able to see posts made by the application
Discussion:
Certain operations such as publishing a status or publishing a photo require an audience. When the user grants an application permission to     perform a publish operation, a default audience is selected as the publication ceiling for the application. This enumerated value allows the application to select which audience to ask the user to grant publish permission for.

Declared In: FBSDKLoginManager.h
```

more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/